# Permanent keyboard focus on windows runtime + second focus on application

Tags: java, windows

I am a little desperate with my recent project. I am not very familiar with how the keyboard focus works. Although I know how to set up a permanent focus on a java UI, I reached my limit with the following attempt:

1. I want to get the keyboard focused permanently (at windows runtime)
2. Other Apllications should still be able to receive input through the keyboard as usual

In other words I want to record the keyboard input while runtime (wow sounds like a keylogger to me 0.0). The idea behind the project is to create an alternative to the command line of windows. A permanently running Java App should check the userinput for keywords and excecute a defined action when this keyword is found at anytime.

Are there any libarys for this purpose ?
Or Native attempts ?
Is it even possible with java?

Im just to inexperienced to figure it out myself. But I tryied my best.

What I tryed you ask? Well:
- Creating a JDialog and set modal to true
- Some experiments with the actionlistener, nothing brought any results which could help with solving my problem :(

I appreciate any tips you have :D
If you have problems with understanding my dificulties write it in the comments. I will edit my Question right away.

PS: I apoligize for my sorry english. The title might be inapropriate but my narrow understanding of the english languish didnt gave me any good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

it was quite easy. All I needed was the globalKeyHook java Api.